# Matlab power spectrum density(PSD) implement equation

Tags: matlab, signals, fft, spectrum

Folks, I am learning how to calculate PSD of a signal with matlab. I know function `Periodogram()` works good, but I want to use `fft` method directly. When I want to learn in detail, I find this website is very helpful:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/power-spectral-density-estimates-using-fft.html

However, I have a problem in the first example. I am a little confused about this statement

```
psdx = (1/(Fs*N)) * abs(xdft).^2;
```

I don't know why using `Fs` and `N` as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `(1/(Fs*N))` is a normalization factor to ensure that the numerical algorithm complies with [Parseval's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem).

Comment: Now I understand why we need `1/N`. But where is `1/Fs` coming from?

Comment: @SihaoSun The `1/Fs` converts from "power __in__ bin" to "power __per__ bin", so that the resulting `psdx` is the power __per frequency interval__ instead of the power __near that frequency__.

Comment: I totally understand your point. One more little question about bin, is bin a line or an area in X-Y coordinate axis?

Comment: @SihaoSun A "bin" in this context is a frequency interval. Strictly speaking it doesn't correspond to anything in the X-Y coordinate plane, but I suppose you could imagine it as a line on the x-axis if you'd like.